# Is it possible to Split a Sentence into list of strings and Uppercase the list of Strings in same line?

Tags: python-3.x, string, split, jupyter-notebook, uppercase

For example:

I want to type this **edit('Let's do this!')** and get this **['LET'S', 'DO', 'THIS!']** answer.

This is my code thus far:

```
### START FUNCTION
def edit(sentence):
    result = (sentence.split())
    return result
### END FUNCTION

edit('Hello, how are you?')
```

Any solution on what to add in the middle code line "result = ..."

Comment: Please add your code directly as text not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use a list comprehension to convert each word of the sentence to upper case.

```
def edit(sentence):
    return [word.upper() for word in sentence.split()]
```

If you want the edit function to be a bit longer.. then it could be

```
def edit(sentence):
    result = (sentence.split())
    result = [word.upper() for word in result]
    return result
```

Another method is to use the map function to apply the upper function to each item in the list.

```
result = list(map(str.upper,sentence.split()))
```

If you want to ignore punctuation, a regex could help you split the words and ignore non-word characters, for example

```
result = [word.group(0).upper() for word in re.finditer("([\w]+)(\W|$)", sentence)]
```

Comment: Is it possible to add upper in this middle section?      result = (sentence.split())

Comment: @Will Answer updated. `sentence.split()` returns a list of strings but upper only works on strings so we need to iterate over each item in the list and convert it that way.